# How to list all endpoints for a spring MVC API ( not spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting an unexpected  404 from a Spring MVC API.  How can I list all endpoints that have been registered?  This is not a spring boot API.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to list all API's that app is exposing, in this case I suggest to use openapi  so that you can see the app API's / execute any of them via browser.

Ex: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

FYI : It could be better if you share code for how you to expose the api since 404 is clearly says that you are not hitting the correct endpoint or you don't have the api for that enpoint